# Why does list of sessions types change when I switch user

Tags: login-screen, gdm, wayland

When I log in with an user I have the following list

- Gnome
- Gnome classique
- Ubuntu

But if I switch user, I have this list

- Gnome
- Gnome classique
- Gnome on Wayland
- Ubuntu
- Ubuntu On Wayland

Whereas I have disabled wayland in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

The main issue is, with the second list it opens a wayland session (even if I don't select
a line that finish with "On Wayland") and it freezes my system (because I use the freon extension that seems to be incompatible with wayland.

I could disable this extension and find an alternative but I would like to understand why the list changes like that

Thank you in advance